# How to Detach a Project from Source Control using Visual Studio 2012?

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

After getting the latest version and mapping the project folder to my local machine, how to detach/unbind it before opening it in Visual Studio since opening it will require a conversion that might affect the original files? The only thing I can think of is deleting the local Visual Studio Source Control Project Metadata File.

Comment: You can always make a backup of the original files prior to opening with Visual Studio. I believe but am not 100% sure that the source control bindings are part of your project file itself.

Comment: There is always a local a ProjectName.cproj file of type "Visual Studio Source Control Project Metadata" when mapping any project. Not sure how the backup will help me here. I want to be completely disconnected from the source.

Comment: The backups would let you test opening with VS and detaching. If that didn't do what you wanted you could restore the files to the original state.

Comment: Even if the conversion happens when you open it, simple perform `Undo Pending Changes` when you're all finished. And don't check anything in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

File - Source Control - Advanced - Change Source Control...

That lets you unbind a project from Source Control. The solution has to be open though.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you just need isolation in which case you really should branch.
You can simply undo the changes after you open the project.  Or, if you really want to detach without VS you can use [TFS power tools](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35775).  That being said, its perfectly safe to use VS to do the detachment.  Because the project will be upgraded as part of the process to detach you will need to undo those changes once you detach the project in VS.

The project will still need to be upgraded at some point in order to run in newer versions of VS.  The good news is w/ VS 2012 those upgrades should be backwards compatible.